# Upsell on magento success.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, configurable-product, onepage-checkout, theme

exist any way in Magento to add Upsell Products at the very bottom of the success.phtml page? If this is important I use Ultimo Theme.

Thank you

Edit:

I found a code, that is seem to be ok for me but in the frontend I have "Record not foundRecord not found "

this is the code, maybe someone can understand more than me:

```
    $orderIcrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();

       $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIcrementId);

       $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();


foreach($orderItems as $orderItem): 




   // Get product object.
   $object = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderItem->getProductId());

   //Get product detail using product id  (Suppose you have product id is : $product_id)
   $_product = $object->load($product_id);

   // Fetch list of upsell product using query.
   $upsell_product = $_product->getUpSellProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('position', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)->addStoreFilter(); 

   //check if record is empty or not
   $count = count($upsell_product);
   if(empty($count)) :
       //if empty
       echo "Record not found";
   else:
     //if result is not empty then get  upsell product detail using foreach loop
      foreach($upsell_product as $_upsell):

         //get detail of single upsell prdocut using upsell product id
         $upsp = $object->load($_upsell->getId());

         echo "Product Name : ". $upsp->getName();
         echo "Poduct url : ". $upsp->getProductUrl();
         echo "Product regular price : ". $upsp->getPrice();

       endforeach;
   endif;

       endforeach;
```

Comment: The items that you purchase are they simple or config product? ... In admin look up the product id then in a template try `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load([product id from admin here]); $upsell = $product->getUpSellProductCollection()->addStoreFilter(); echo 'number of upsell = ' . count($upsell);` How many upsell did it return?

Comment: the upsell's are from the config product

Comment: `$order->getAllItems()` will return both simple and config, so one of those item my not have upsell

Comment: i understand and what I need to do?

Comment: I have ultimo theme, maybe is a easy way? to display that upsell's in the success page?

Comment: Look up you last order then check each item to see if they have simple item? A quick way to test would be to copy the above code to a temple file (ie cart) then replace `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(admin increment id here); and refresh that page and debug

Comment: in this order is only one configurable product, and in the order now exist only simpe associated products. But the upsels are configured to the congfigurable product

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36043/discussion-between-r-s-and-robertd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added `$order->getAllItems()` it will return all items from recent order in current session.
You can use Thank you page module https://www.magecheckout.com/magento-better-thank-you-page.html

It is easy to implement

Comment: hi no thank you, I prefer to do this manually instead use extensions, anyway thank you for your answer but you don't help me with this.